# eliminar historial callback Android

Tags: android, callback

tengo una aplicacion la cual consta de 3 activities , `A`, `B`, `C` , ya tengo que en `onBackPressed` de `B` y `C` me devuelva a `A` :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

sin embargo en `A` quiero que al precionar botón atras me saque de la aplicación , no quiero que se devuelva ni a `B` ni a `C`, tengo el siguiente código en `onBackPressed`  pero no funciona

```
 finish();
            super.onBackPressed();
```

y no puedo poner igual que en los otros el intent ya que  al precionar atras se quedaría infinito en la actividad `A`

Comment: a que te refieres cuando dices que no funciona , que pasa cuando presionas back?

Comment: se regresa a la actividad anterior A/ B

Comment: intentaste con : intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Comment: te refieres a al actividad A? pero ese intent debo activarlo también como startActivity ? por que si lo hago entonces cada que le de boton atras me va a brir la activity A y el usuario nunca va a salir precionando ese botón

Comment: puedes indicar mejor como es el flujo de tu app, que actividad abre a cual , para tener una idea más clara

Comment: pues de hecho todo el flujo debe dirijirse a A, y cuando llegue allí, al darle boton atrás no exista historial sino que de una me saque al "escritorio" me saque de la app

Comment: tu actividad A creala como single task en el manifest

Comment: Ah perfecto, Muchas gracias!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes definir tu `Actividad` como `singleTask` en el `AndroidManifest.xml` para que solo exista un `Activity` A y no cree nuevas actividades según tus requerimientos.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActividadA"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
```